# Что значит исключение в тесте?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

[image: скриншот исключения]

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void WithSpaceTest()
 {
    var line = " hello world ";

    var result = TableParser.FieldsParserTask.ParseLine(line);
    var strResult = result.ToArray();
    var expected = new[] { "hello", "world" };
    Assert.AreEqual(expected,strResult);
 }
```

Comment: Похоже, expected!=strResult. Используйте пошаговую отладку.

Comment: Кстати, для сравнения коллекций есть `CollectionAssert`

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Они равны точно, проверял уже через отладку

Comment: Вы сравниваете ссылки. Они не равны.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен, сорь за тупость.